# Is .net inherently insecure

Tags: windows, security

I keep hearing people say that .Net is insecure.  When I ask for details I never get them.  Is there any actual technical reason that .Net, or Windows operating systems are not secure?

I have heard people say that the architecture of the Windows Kernel allows hackers and malware to exploit the system.  I can't find any information about this online, can anyone elaborate?

Is it possible that people are referring to issues that were valid back in the days of Windows 3.1 or XP?

-BTR

Comment: This question is really too broad. If you don't know the details of those claims we can't confirm/refute some offhand comment. Also, almost nothing in IT is inherently secure or not - depends on what you do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Recent Windows kernels (mainly Win 10) are much better then their reputation among some people. Win 10 can actually be pretty secure. Also while .NET had its vulnerabilities, other platforms did too. Lately, Microsoft is investing a lot into really securing the platform, and I think it's starting to be successful. It's hard to get rid of past reputation though.

I think it's not one platform being more or less secure than another. You can write secure applications in most programming languages on almost any platform. The question is how difficult that is, and how prepared the average developer (or the team you choose) is to do so. I think there *are* differences in this regard, and those (at least in my experience) do not favor the Microsoft world, but from here it's really getting very opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is actually save from hackers , but I would not say that .Net is insecure:

This is a paragraph from  wikipedia about .Net security:

> .NET Framework has its own security mechanism with two general
>   features: Code Access Security (CAS), and validation and verification.
>   CAS is based on evidence that is associated with a specific assembly.
>   Typically the evidence is the source of the assembly (whether it is
>   installed on the local machine or has been downloaded from the
>   intranet or Internet). CAS uses evidence to determine the permissions
>   granted to the code. Other code can demand that calling code be
>   granted a specified permission. The demand causes CLR to perform a
>   call stack walk: every assembly of each method in the call stack is
>   checked for the required permission; if any assembly is not granted
>   the permission a security exception is thrown.

According to this .Net seems safe for me.
Here is the link on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Security

And this is a paragraph from Security in the .NET Framework by microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkytk30f(v=vs.110).aspx:

> The common language runtime and the .NET Framework provide many useful
>   classes and services that enable developers to easily write secure
>   code and enable system administrators to customize the permissions
>   granted to code so that it can access protected resources. In
>   addition, the runtime and the .NET Framework provide useful classes
>   and services that facilitate the use of cryptography and role-based
>   security.

I think that the most important thing is your code (how is it written)!

Comment: The presence of one security mechanism does not mean the entire system is secure. It may be, but this doesn't answer the question.